# $\sqrt[4] {81}$ (find the root if it's a real number)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\sqrt[5]{(-5)^5}$

Simplify the root:

$\sqrt[4]{x^4}$

$-\sqrt[3]{x^9}$

$-\sqrt{x^{18}}$

Thank you to everyone who replies <3

Comment: By index $4 \sqrt{81}$ do you mean the fourth root of $81, \sqrt[4]{81}$  To write roots in $\LaTeX$, which are easier to read, you enclose in dollar signs \sqrt[index]{number to take the root of} so to get $\sqrt[4]{81}$ I wrote \sqrt[4]{81}

Comment: I believe that I do. I'm sorry, I must seem like an invalid.

Comment: It said "index" in my book, so I assumed that was what it was called.

Comment: oh sweet. I only learned the symbol for square root from imgur. lol. Thank you.

Comment: No, many people don't know $\LaTeX$, but it makes math much easier to read.  [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a place to start.  The point about right-clicking and picking Show Math as -> TeX Commands is a great way to learn.

Comment: Please check whether these edits retain your original intentions.

Comment: They definitely covey what I was trying to better than I initially did, and I appreciate it SO much :) Thank you for the edit-love.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  Do you know that powers and roots are inverse functions, so  $\sqrt [a]b=b^{\frac 1a}$?  Then do you know a law of exponents about $(a^b)^c$?  These will take you far.

Comment: The teacher that I have isn't the greatest. When I was attempting to learn factoring and the distributive prop. he told us NOT to use FOIL. It made life pretty hard, as that's how I learned from the start. He just has a different teaching style I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Brace yourselves, for square roots are coming..

Assuming that the question is wether

$$ \sqrt[5]{(-5)^5}$$

is a real number or not, note that

$$(-5)^5=(-1\cdot5)^5=(-1)^5 5^5=-5^5$$

$$\sqrt[5]{(-5)^5}=\sqrt[5]{-1}\sqrt[5]{5^5} $$

so it is not real.

For the simplifications note that

$$ \sqrt[n]{a}=(a)^{1/n}$$

and

$$ (a^{n})^{m}=a^{nm}$$

Comment: So any negatives are not real numbers? these square roots are dark and full of terrors

Comment: @Nivalth $(-1)$ _doesn't_ have a real _fifth_ root?!  You may want to look at what you wrote again...